# Different fruit drinks

Tags: combinatorics

If I have $3$ different kinds of fruit, and I can make a fruit drink using as many different fruits as I like, I can make 7 different fruit drinks. Correct?

How many different kinds of fruit drink can I make with 9 different kinds of fruit?

Comment: This is not calculus, but combinatorics. Also, show how you found that 3 gives 7, and why you cannot use the same logic to find the answer for 9.

Answer (score 2):

For each of the $3$ fruits, you can either include it in your drink or not, giving $2^3-1=7$ possible drinks (I subtract $1$, because no one likes an empty drink).

If I have $n$ fruits, I similarly have $2^n-1$ possible drinks.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

$$N=C^9_{1}+C^9_{2}+C^9_{3}+C^9_{4}+C^9_{5}+C^9_{6}+C^9_{7}+C^9_{8}+C^9_{9}$$

where $N$ is a number of different fruit drinks and $C^n_{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)! }$ (number of combinations) .